# How to send a message to a Google Pub/Sub topic upon Cloud Build failures?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build

I'd like to set up my Cloud Build pipeline to send a message to a specific topic in Google Pub/Sub upon build failure. Is there an easy way to do this with Cloud Build? Sort of like a "finally" block in a "try catch" statement or something? There's a few steps where failures may happen, so I'd rather not repeatedly check for failures after each step.

Comment: Do you want to know the Cloud Build build status?

Comment: I want to know when the Cloud Build pipeline fails, whether its due to a step failing or someone manually stops it. When it fails or when it is stopped, I'd like to receive a message on a Pub/Sub topic that I choose.

Comment: Something native exist, i don't know if it's what you are looking for https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications

Comment: Alright I can work with that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Guillaume Blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) in a comment above, Cloud Build natively provides build status updates via Pub/Sub, see https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications

While you could build your own, you would only be able to catch failures that happen during the build, and would miss on certain failures (e.g. cancellations, ...)